# Nestjs build not working as expected when NODE_ENV is set to production

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

Error: Property 'objectId' does not exist on type '{}'

Steps to reproduce:

Set the NODE_ENV environment variable to 'production'.
Build the NestJS application.
Trigger the code snippet mentioned below.
Code Snippet:

```
const mapObject = new Map()

const employee = mapObject.get("keyName");

if (!employee) {
  throw new ServerException({
  });
}
const objectId = employee.objectId;
```

Expected behavior:
The build process should complete successfully without any errors, even when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to 'production'.

Actual behavior:
When the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to 'production', the build throws the following error: "Property 'objectId' does not exist on type '{}'."

Additional information:

This issue does not occur in the development environment.
The error occurs when trying to access the 'objectId' property of the 'employee' object retrieved from the 'mapObject' map.

node version :- 18.16

Packages versions
"@nestjs/common": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^9.0.0",
"@nestjs/cli": "^9.0.0",